# Linked server query takes long time unless filter is hard-coded

Tags: sql-server, performance, linked-server

I have a simple select query I'm executing as below:

```
SELECT Id FROM [LinkedServer].[Catalog].[dbo].[someTable] WHERE date = @someDate AND Id IN (SELECT Id FROM ids)
```

`ids` is a single-column table with a list of 50 or so IDs (FWIW the IDs are all strings, not ints), and `LinkedServer` is a server across the Atlantic. `someTable` is a mapping of many (~300m) `(date,ID)` pairs to values and has the appropriate PK.

The curious thing that I cannot get my head around is that this query takes 10s to execute - but if I replace `(SELECT Id FROM ids)` with the hard-coded contents of ids, so the query reads

```
SELECT Id FROM [LinkedServer].[Catalog].[dbo].[someTable] WHERE date = @someDate AND Id IN ('id1','id2', ..., 'id50')
```

say, it executes in <1s. Can anyone explain this difference and give any ideas how I might carry over the performance of the hard-coded query into the true one?

Comment: I'd try to make a stored procedure on the linked server that accepts table-valued parameter. When you call such procedure the table of IDs should be sent to the remote server in one batch, stored there as an implicit temp table and used there without trips back for each row.

Answer (score 1):

The first query is running in a Distributed fashion across 2 servers. This can be slow because Server A doesn't know the Statistics for Server B and a proper Execution Plan Can't be produced.

The second query "Transmits" the query to the Server B, the query then runs exclusively on Server B, and finally the results are transmitted back to Server A.